# Python 3: What should I do about this the Internal Python error in the inspect module

Tags: python, jupyter, python-3.7

I have been trying to import these modules:

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import mathplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

The Error message I get is:
Using TensorFlow backend.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Coupled with a long list of code, how do I solve this?

Comment: Include the traceback in your question.

Comment: Scan through the traceback message from the bottom upwards: there may be some useful information as to what the actual problem is, such as a missing module.